# Работа с рандомом: победить с вероятностью 95%

Tags: python

В общем у обоих игроков есть общая сила, я хотел сделать так, что бы у кого сила больше, тот побеждал c вероятностью 95%, а у кого меньше, тоже был шанс победить, но с 5%, как тут правильно сделать?

`player1win = random.random() * (power1 + power2) < power1`

Comment: что должна делать приведенная строчка кода?

Comment: Это переменная выигрыша игрока if player1win то победа и тд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переведем логическое условие в значения 0/1, создадим граничное значение B, которое равно 0.95 для случая, когда первый сильнее, и 0.05 иначе. Если случайное значение в диапазоне `0..B`. то первый выиграл:

```
player1win = random.random() < (0.05 + 0.9 * int(power1 > power2))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Чтобы подчекнуть, что сумма вероятностей равна всегда единице: `alpha  + (1 - 2 * alpha) * (a.power > b.power)` (assert alpha < .5)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое